# Install ffmpeg with laravel on elastic beanstalk

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, ffmpeg

My Laravel application needs to use the ffmpeg library.I need it to get a thubmnail image from an input video file. On my local system , I have used **http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/11/02/install-ffmpeg-3-2-via-ppa-ubuntu-16-04/** and **https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg** composer package . But I dont know how to include the ffmpeg library on elastic beanstalk. Can someone please tell me the procedure? I have read that you may have to put it in a .ebextensions directory, but I dont know how to do that. I have tried this link [Install ffmpeg on elastic beanstalk using ebextensions config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340771/install-ffmpeg-on-elastic-beanstalk-using-ebextensions-config) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install ffmpeg on elastic beanstalk using ebextensions config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340771/install-ffmpeg-on-elastic-beanstalk-using-ebextensions-config)

Comment: I have tried that . That doesn't work.

Comment: What we did - get stand alone version of FFMPEG and simply use it without installing.

Comment: @Justinas Are you saying you used the composer package without the ppa package?

Comment: @comos234 No, we use direct commands without any modules/packages.